# Multiline title vertical alignment using classicthesis and arsclassica

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, titlesec, classicthesis

I would like to align the 2nd line of my title to have the same baseline with the chapter number. What I have now is [image]

, but I would like to have[image]

instead.

I found that the tweak in [How to get multi-line chapter name with ClassicThesis package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7798/how-to-get-multi-line-chapter-name-with-classicthesis-package) still leave the alignment problem (and I can't comment there), which are either change the `\titleformat{\chapter}[block]` to `\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]` or 
the use of `tabularx` package, which results in
[image]

Although it does look better, but IMHO doesn't look quite right.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,BCOR=5mm,footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% Classic Thesis Style loader
\makeatother
\input{classicthesis-config.tex}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\makeatletter
% use Latin Modern instead of Computer Modern sans serif
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Conclusions and Recommendations}
\end{document}
```

, where by the `classicthesis-config.tex` is exactly the same as the LyX version in https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/. Here, in the MWE the font is different, but I just leave that since it's not relevant.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: There is no need to say thanks in your question. Just  upvote any answer that you find helpful. This may be strange at first but you will get used to it. You can also accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. :) BTW, please always make it a habit to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @hpesoj626 Oh, all right. I've added the MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be to use `\formatchapter` with two `minipage`s (one for the number, the other for the title) with bottom alignment:

```
\documentclass[english,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,twoside,
openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,
headinclude,BCOR=5mm,footinclude=true,
cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config.tex}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{babel}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}

\renewcommand\formatchapter[1]{% 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.15\linewidth}
    \chapterNumber
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
    \raggedright\spacedallcaps{#1}
  \end{minipage}
} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Conclusions and Recommendations}

\chapter{A Really Long Example Title Spanning Three Lines}

\end{document}
```

An image of a title spanning two lines:

[image]

An image of a title spanning three lines:

[image]

I suppressed parts of the example code that were not relevant to the problem discussed.

Comment: Thanks! This works very well. The only thing I change is the second `minipage` width, which is from `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth} ...` to `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}...` to allow for longer sentences per line.

Comment: Thanks, that worked beautifully! The lower line is exactly where it would be in a non-multiline title. =)

Comment: Why this is not the default outcome?

Comment: I have tried to implement this, and it looks like the examples shown here, but what is not shown is that (in my case) there is a larger space between the chapter title and the text below. Can anyone confirm or suggest a fix to this?
(Also, this change slightly moves the chapter title to the right, but I guess that's not a big deal. )

Comment: Edit to my comment above: This only happens when I change the widths of the minipages to 0.15 and 0.85, and then only for the long chapter titles. Should this not be possible?