# Disable hyphenation in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyphenation, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` and `arsclassica` to write some book. In order to prevent hyphenation in section title, I added

```
\titleformat{\section}
    {\raggedright}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
```

which I got from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109201/classicthesis-multiline-section-headings-do-not-work). Consider this MWE.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage[inner=2.2cm,outer=1.8cm,bottom=2.7cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\titleformat{\section}
{\raggedright}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{The Separation Axioms and Continuous Real-Valued Functions}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It worked for the section title, but I still get hyphenation in ToC. How to disable hyphenation in ToC as well?

Comment: If you want to disable hyphenation for all entries in ToC, LoF and LoT: `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}\makeatother`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable hyphenation for all entries in ToC, LoF and LoT:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage[inner=2.2cm,outer=1.8cm,bottom=2.7cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\titleformat{\section}
{\raggedright}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{The Separation Axioms and Continuous Real-Valued Functions}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```