# Is there an alternative for using \mbox to prevent ugly hyphenation in the toc

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

Assume I have a long chapter title `\chapter{one two three four five six seven eight nine ten}` that appears in the table of contents like this:

> 1. one two three four five six se-
>
> ven eight nine ten

This seems ugly to me. I would like to have it like:

> 1. one two three four five six
>
> seven eight nine ten

But if I use `\chapter{one two three four five six \mbox{seven} eight nine ten}` the line in the table of contents will be too long, so is there an alternative to have a linebreak in the table of contents without hyphenation and without having a line that is too long?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. With index, you mean the table of contents?

Comment: Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: arrange that your chapter headings are set `\raggedright` then tex won't hyphenate them.

Comment: by the way you mean Table of Contents not  Index (Index in English means the alphabetical list, usually at the end of the book)

Comment: Have you tried the `\hyphenpenalty` option? It is intended for that, you can set it to `\hyphenpenalty=10000` to prevent _most_ hyphens. And modify it before and after including the index.

Comment: yeah i mean toc, documentclass is scrreprt. The problem is that I want Latex to hyphenate in the toc, but not for this special chapter, so it wouldn't help to use the hyphenpenalty option for the whole toc..

Comment: the \raggedright{one two three four five six seven eight nine ten} option seems to have no consequence for the toc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable hyphenation for all entries in ToC, LoF and LoT:

(Remember to compile code twice)

[image]

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage[inner=2.2cm,outer=1.8cm,bottom=2.7cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\titleformat{\section}
{\raggedright}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{The Separation Axioms and Continuous Real-Valued Functions}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Taken from--https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430273/197451